# How to get Server ip address to send in mail in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send mails in nodejs.   I am embedding hyperlink to mailbody it is working fine.

My sample mailbody is below

```
 `This is confirmation mail.\n
                       please click below link to login
              http://${req.headers.host}/login\n\n
              \n`
```

Observe the scenario, If i open my page as `localhost:port` it is sending mail with `localhost:port` when I open with `Ipaddress:port` then it is sending with `Ipaddress:port`.

Here comes the my problem I got mail successfully,now I opened my mail in another system and from there I click on the link then it is getting the `server can't be reached.` This is quite straight forward as the server is running on another machine but I am trying to open in different machine with `locahost`.

So how can i send the server ip address in that mail. I have also seen about `server.address().address` but how to use I got confused.

Comment: you cannot access the server running on local from another machine

Comment: either you have to stay on local on host this server on some cloud

Comment: @Asad I can access server from another machine with `serveripaddress:port` but here in mail i am getting `localhost:port`. So my question is how to get serverip address to send in mail as like `req.headers.host`

Comment: check my answer @cheran

Comment: req.remoteAddress works

Comment: @UditKumawat I needed the ip of server not the remote system ip where I am running because Server was listnening to port in that server machine

Answer (score 0):

are you using ExpressJs you can use use this 
     `req.hostname` on nodejs Server try this and let me know if works or `req.ip`

Comment: when I use `req.hostname` it gives localhost and when `req.ip` it gives empty as `::`

Comment: how u accessing this server on another machine ?

Comment: By ip of server  I can access

Comment: well how is this posible that ip is not sending to the nodejs server in request object it alwasy goes in request object well u try this `var host = req.get('host');` ? @charantej

Comment: No when I am accesing from another machine and If I try from there mail is sending the hyperlink with `Ip address` only but when I am accessing in server machine with `localhost` in place of `IP` I am getting localhost in the hyperlink of mail. So here I need to get the IP which ever case i open through `localhost` or `IP address`.

Comment: ok ok i got ur problem so when . u make hyprlink to send email u are not making correct link u have to save that link through which email verification is going to be done

Comment: How to save I am fetching `req.headers.host` then it is showing only localhost

Comment: share ur bth apis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142902/discussion-between-asad-and-charan-tej).